# Event-/Input system with SFML: Cannot move diagonally in 2D

Tags: c++, input, sfml, events

I am a beginner in anything with game development. I written a small prototype in which i can move a square around with the arrow keys. For that i use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).

At the moment i experiment around with my **Event System**: First, to keep things simple, i was polling for the arrow keys using [sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed()](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#a80a04b2f53005886957f49eee3531599), which works fine for this small kind of "game"

```
// in handleUserInput():
if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))
{
        player_.moveLeft();
}

// in player the player class:
void moveLeft()
{
    velocity.x = -x_speed; // sf::Vector2f
}

// in my player-class update() method:
void update()
{
// Out of bounds check and so on...
shape.move(velocity);
velocity.x = 0;
velocity.y = 0;
}
```

With this i was able to move horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

Then i moved to create my "real" EventSystem based on callbacks.
It wraps around [sf::Window::pollEvent()](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Window.php#a338e996585faf82e93069858e3b531b7). E.g. i register a callback method for the event type [sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Event.php#af41fa9ed45c02449030699f671331d4aac3c7abfaa98c73bfe6be0b57df09c71b). So i changed my code to first register for the movement keys

```
event_system_.registerCallback(sf::Event::KeyPressed, [&] (const sf::Event& event)
    {
        switch(event.key.code)
        {
        case sf::Keyboard::Left:
            log->info() << "Moving Left";
            player_.moveLeft();
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Right:
            log->info() << "Moving Right";
            player_.moveRight();
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Up:
            log->info() << "Moving Up";
            player_.moveUp();
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Down:
            log->info() << "Moving Down";
            player_.moveDown();
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
            window_.close();
            break;
        }
    });
```

The problem i encountered was, that i **couldn't** **move** **diagonally** anymore.
After adding the loggin parts i found out, that when i keep two arrow keys pressed the only event that gets fired over and over again was the key pressed latest (e.g. i try to press *Left & Down* and pressed the *Down-Key* *slightly later* the *Down-Event would be captured over and over* again and the *Left-Event only once*).

After that i changed my code not to reset the **velocity** in my player's *update*-method and also registered for [sf::Event::KeyReleased](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Event.php#af41fa9ed45c02449030699f671331d4aaa5bcc1e603d5a6f4c137af39558bd5d1) so that it would reset the x/y-part of the velocity when the corresponding key was released.

```
event_system_.registerCallback(sf::Event::KeyReleased, [&] (const sf::Event& event)
    {
        switch(event.key.code)
        {
        case sf::Keyboard::Left:
        case sf::Keyboard::Right:
            log->info() << "Stopped moving horizontally";
            player_.velocity.x = 0;
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Up:
        case sf::Keyboard::Down:
            log->info() << "Stopped moving vertically";
            player_.velocity.y = 0;
            break;
        }
    });
```

But somehow this does not seem right to me (But it wouldn't seem right to me to poll for every single possible input manually - So i think events is the things to take). Could anyone give me a hint what i am doing wrong and how to do it better?

Kind Regards

Comment: Some people (like me) like to have a state for each key. A variable named, for example, key_right that we put to *true* when it is pressed and *false* when it is released. We then look up that state on update to move accordingly.

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens How do you look up the state would be the question: Do you poll, or use callbacks?

Comment: You use both the onKeyPress and onKeyRelease callbacks to change the state of the key, but afterwards, you poll this state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally use the keyboard class that allows you to query the state of keys instead of waiting for an event.

The documentation is [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0-fr/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php)

One of the reasons I prefer this method is that you can check the status of the key from almost anywhere in the code, and you don't have to store the state of the keys yourself.

> f::Keyboard can retrieve the state of a key at any time (you don't
>   need to store and update a boolean on your side in order to know if a
>   key is pressed or released), and you always get the real state of the
>   keyboard, even if keys are pressed or released when your window is out
>   of focus and no event is triggered.

The other obvious advantage is that you can check the state of multiple keys at the same time, hence making it easy to detect key combinations :

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left) && sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))player_.moveDownLeft();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why you prefer to poll?

Comment: Edited the answer